# How to pass data from a class to another class? Qt

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I'm working with qt and sqllite.Here is my code:

```
    bool Login::isInfoValid(){

    email = ui->emailEdit->text();
    password = ui->passwordEdit->text();

    QSqlQuery checkQuery(myDatabase);
    checkQuery.prepare("Select * FROM Customers WHERE Email = (:email) AND Password = (:password)");
    checkQuery.bindValue(":email",email);
    checkQuery.bindValue(":password",password);

    if(checkQuery.exec()){
        if(checkQuery.next()){
            exists = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Login class email data: " <<getEmailData()<<endl;
    return exists;
}

void Login::on_loginButton_clicked()
{
    if(isInfoValid()){
        UserInterface userinterface;
        userinterface.setModal(true);
        userinterface.exec();
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<"Login is not successful.Please check your email or password. ";
    }

}

std::string Login::getEmailData(){
    return email.toStdString();
}
```

This code is checking the login information from Sqllite database and if info is true, it opens another windows for user interface. However, when I try to reach for examples, email data from user interface class, I can not see any data in it.

Sample code for userinterface class:

```
void UserInterface::on_sendButton_clicked()
{
    Login login;
    std::cout<<"User interface class Email data: "<<login.getEmailData()<<endl;
}
```

I'm using getter function to return private data. As you can see in the pictures,when I use this getter in Login class, it shows the data inside of Email variable.

[image]

How can I pass the email data to the User interface class?

Comment: *'Qt'* -> [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) – have you looked for?

Comment: @Aconcagua I did not understand what do you mean? I'm using slots for click actions.

Comment: `void Login::on_loginButton_clicked() { if(isInfoValid()){ /*signal with login data*/ } }` – the main application should provide a slot for (you don't want to keep the login dialog while the main user interface is running, do you?). The main application would in the slot open the new UI window. You could pass on the login data to the latter one via constructor, setters or another slot, depending on what appears most appropriate to you.

Comment: I personally would do it the other way round: First create the user inferface with all of its contents initially hidden (alternatively entire window hidden), then open the login dialog overlaying this window and on success show the contents in the window – having a slot passed login data to. Even more elegant: Integrate the login directly into the main user interface such that you don't ever see a separate login dialog.

Answer (score 1):

in Login.h define a signal

```
signals:
    void loginResult(bool isResultOk);
```

in the UserInterface.h define the slot

```
slots:
   void onLoginResult(bool isResultOk);
```

somewhere connect them

```
connect(myPointerLogin, &Login::loginResult, 
           myPointerUserInterface, &UserInterface::onLoginResult);
```

then in the UserInterface write the method with the logic

```
void UserInterface::onLoginResult(bool resultOk)
{
    qDebug() << "Login result was: " << resultOk;
}
```

this is of course an example of how qt works with signals - slots
you can adapt the code and pass as parameter other objects...

Comment: I could not understand how to pass data to other class tbh.